Как распарсить строку на ключ/значение?
Не понимаю как из строки:
"ST00012|Name=Мр"Водоканал"|PersonalAcc=40702813070000012а3456|BankName=Банк"
Можно получить объект ключ/значение

Что из этого ключ, а что значение? Добавьте в сам вопрос исходную строку и желаемый результат

Еще можно попробовать распарсить через регулярное выражение: (?:([^|=]+)=([^|]+)|([^|=]+))\|?. $1 - ключ, $2 - значение, $3 - просто значение.

Сплитим изначальную строку по | - это как я понял наш делитель между ключ=значение.
На выходе получим что-то типо:
['ST00012', 'Name=Мр "Водоканал"', 'PersonalAcc=40702813070000012а3456', 'BankName=Банк']
Дальше нам нужно пробежаться по этому массиву и сделать еще раз split каждого элемента массива по = который разделяет ключ и значение, и записать все это в объект - это все мы делаем в .reduce()


const rawString = 'ST00012|Name=Мр "Водоканал"|PersonalAcc=40702813070000012а3456|BankName=Банк';

const parsedObject = rawString.split("|").reduce((acc, item) =>
{
  const [key, value] = item.split("=");
  
  acc[key] = value;
  
  return acc;
}, {})

console.info(parsedObject)




Второй вариант, где не будут добавляться ключи без значений.


const rawString = 'ST00012|Name=Мр "Водоканал"|PersonalAcc=40702813070000012а3456|BankName=Банк';

const parsedObject = rawString.split("|").reduce((acc, item) =>
{
  const [key, value] = item.split("=");
  
  if (value !== undefined)
  {
    acc[key] = value;
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {})

console.info(parsedObject)




Вот только первый ключ смотрится не красиво...

Ну тут зависит от того, как захочет его обработать автор.

@SwaD if(!key) return acc...

@ΝNL993 вы перепутали key c value :)

@OliverPatterson верно. Тогда: if(value === void 0) return acc

@ΝNL993 вы явно что-то дико путаете)

@OliverPatterson нет. Вы меня не поняли. Попробуйте код

@ΝNL993 впервые вижу использование void 0 и не понимаю какой смысл, чисто меньше буковок?) undefined очевиднее

@OliverPatterson В старых браузерах undefined может быть переобъявлен (пример: var undefined = 123; console.log(undefined) // 1), и тогда может появиться ошибка. Это очень редкий кейс, но я на всякий случай, стараюсь писать void 0.

@OliverPatterson можете погуглить: undefined vs void 0
